# Implementing A Custom Lock Screen Image Via GPO

Tags: group-policy

I have a Domain running at the Windows Server 2008 functional level, which cannot be upgraded currently due to logistics reasons. I have a group of Student-access clients all running Windows Server 2012 and would like to implement a custom lock/login screen background image across them. I cannot seem to find anything that would let me aside from running custom software which I am adverse to do.

I have tried looking for registry edits, GPO's(which would be preferrable), Group Policy Preferences and have found nothing that would permit this, I do know if I my Domain was running Windows Server 2012 there is a GPO built just for this but do not have access to that. Is there any way I can achieve this using no 3rd party software and/or preferably through Group Policy?

The update at: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2787100/en-us
doesn't apply here due to functional level 2008

http://www.howtogeek.com/112110/how-to-set-a-custom-logon-screen-background-on-windows-7/ is how I did this for my Windows 7 clients but doesn't work on Server clients.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found to achieve your required outcome is by setting registry values, which I have implemented across the networks I manage via Group Policy Preferences.

The following URL should help you out,

http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/04/best-practice-how-to-use-group-policy-to-configure-windows-7-logon-ui-background-wallpaper/

Chris

Comment: Thats the way I did my windows 7 clients, but it doesnt apply to Server clients